# Clustered quartz 2.x job + spring 4.1

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have integrated spring with quartz and below is the config that I have used:

```
 <bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="jndiDataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
            <value>applicationContext</value>
        </property>
        <property name="schedulerName" value="PimsJobs"/>
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Though I have set property isClustered as true still I see in logs

```
 [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 108) Scheduler PimsJobs_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

Also I see below logs :

```
36:31,747 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 108) Starting Quartz Scheduler now
    36:31,765 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 108) ClusterManager: detected 1 failed or resta
    d instances.
    36:31,766 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 108) ClusterManager: Scanning for instance "NON
    USTERED"'s failed in-progress jobs.
```

Comment: Off topic but also related: Do you know that you should not use Quartz clustering on separate machines, unless their clocks are synchronized? http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering

Comment: Yes I know @RicardoVila..thanks for reminding.

Comment: I'm also facing an issue related to quartz scheduler where the instance deployed in a cluster throws similar error.